# disconnecting from router web site

Tags: windows, wireless-networking

What is the best way to disconnect from a routers web inteface?   Logon is required but there 
is no way to log off.   What I do now is close the browser and clear the history and I'm not 
even sure that does it.   what do you think?

Answer (score 2):

Generally just clearing the cookies and then closing the browser will log you out.
The login page sets a cookie, and clearing the cookie out will log you out.